# Upgrade rxjs 6: this._subscribe is not a function at PromiseObservable.Observable.subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs6

After upgrade:
 Angular "5.2.0" -> "6.0.2" and 
 rxjs": "^5.2.0", -> "rxjs": "^6.0" and "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",

I've found this error on the browser:

```
TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function
at PromiseObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:161)
at eval (subscribeTo.js:21)
```

Then I've installed: **npm i -g rxjs-tslint** 
and run **rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p path-to-tsconfig.ts** 
all paths have been updated but still same error on browser.

Answer (score 1):

The code must be updated in order to work with rxjs6.

Here is the reason why PromiseObservable fails:

> All observable classes (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.5.8/src/observable) have been removed from v6, in favor of existing or new operators that perform the same operations as the class methods.
>
> For example, ArrayObservable.create(myArray) can be replaced by from(myArray), or the new operator fromArray().

In our case:
**new PromiseObservable(xml2js(responseXML.text()) must be replaced by from(xml2js(responseXML.text());**

-> flatMap(...) is replaced by:
**.pipe(
          mergeMap(...)**

Another example  that I could find on my code is:

**Observable.of() by of()**

For further information, please, check the follow doc:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths